# how to test my tsdx ui library package locally on react.js project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, tsdx

i use tsdx to create a react ui library, and i want to test it on my next.js project before pushing it to the npm package.

- i have try `npm link` , it works well in the beginning but when i change any thing in the package files it gave me an error, module not found, but it still in the node_modules folder.
- i have try to run  `yarn install <tsdx-project-path >` but it still gave me an error

so is there any way to include my tsdx ui library in my project locally.

Answer (score 0):

let's think you have following folder structure.

```
|---/current-project
|---/tsdx-package
```

So you need to run `npm install ../tsdx-package` from inside `current-project`. I'm pretty sure you forgot to add `../` to your package path.